# user has no write permission on his owned folders?

Tags: debian, apache2

i am working on `Debian10 with php8 fpm + apache2` , I've created a new user with a group `username:username` , and i've set a home directory for this user located at

```
/home/username/www
```

of course i've `chmod -R` all the folders and files to `username:username` , before it was www-data when the files was inside `/var/html`

so basically i have a small script trying to write a cache folder but it is not working when i chmod the folders to username:username , its only work if i chmod the folders to www-data ?

the cache folder chown 755 , and it working fine if owned by `www-data` not `username`

is it possible to allow `username` has a write permission like `www-data`?

> PS : username is an example for the real one

Comment: My own approach: set chown user:www-data, chmod 750, and 770 only to directories that shoud be writable by apache. This way user is the owner and can do anything, www-data has read acces (or +write when needed), and other denied.

Comment: @Chris can u post ur full answer? so if its work ill mark it as sovled

Answer (score 0):

A *possible* approach to let `username` control stuff, while `www-data` has read only  access for security reasons and write access only where its needed:

- Set `username` as owner and `www-data` as group

  ```
  chown -R username:www-data /home/username/www
  ```
- Give full access to owner (read/write/exec: 7) and read only access to group (read/exec: 5). The `Other` group here has no access (0).

  ```
  chmod -R 750 /home/username/www
  ```
- Give write access to `www-data` where its needed:

  ```
  chmod -R 770 /home/username/www/path/writable/by/webserver
  ```

Files created by webserver will be fully owned by itself (`www-data:www-data`) but the directory owner (`username`) still can move them.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you install PHP-FPM it installs a single pool which runs as the `www-data` user. If you change the `user` and `group` in `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` to the right user, then your script will run as the user, and `www-data` will not need write permissions.

Your config have these 2 lines by default:

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
```

Replace those lines with:

```
user = username
group = username
```

Restart the FPM daemon

```
service php8.0-fpm restart
```

Comment: okay , i got it , but i have multiple website on the server

Comment: Typically you would create a pool per site in that case. This way each can have a dedicated user account separate from others.